# Retrieving data from EditText in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

How do I work with whatever the user enters into an EditText, in Java? For just one example, maybe the user enters "I had a great time this weekend!" into an EditText (like a Facebook update or Tweet). I want to do something with "I had a great time this weekend!" so how do I use Java to affect it in the app????

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get a value back from an `EditText` with

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String value = editText.getText().toString();
```

I recommend `.trim()`'ing this value, since you probably don't want the trailing whitespace users tend to leave.

You should use a `Button` onClick event to call the above methods, because it's more or less likely to be the UX you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
Editable editable = edit.getText();
String allTheText = editable.toString();
```

Replace editTextID with the ID for your EditText.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for get data from Edit text

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String value = editText.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code also:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextID);

String string_object=String.valueOf(edit.getText());
```