# How to add city selection to weather app?

Tags: java, android, weather

My weather app uses Openweathermap API. But i can only get forecast for the city I put in the code.

I want to add an option so the user types his city name and get the weather forecast for it.

I've added an EditText to the layout but don't know how to get the data from it and use as the city name input.

Here is my code:

```
package com.hamed.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.hamed.myapplication.view.dataModel.WeatherInfo;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 * Created by Hamed on 8/20/2017.
 */

public class ApiService {
    private static final String TAG = "ApiService";
    private Context context;


    public ApiService (Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void getCurrentWeather(final OnWeatherInfoRecieved onWeatherInfoRecieved, String cityName){
        JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=ahvaz&apikey=01a477912e47daf2010808cc62015829",
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.toString());
                onWeatherInfoRecieved.onRecieved(parseResponseToWeatherInfo(response));

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: "+error.toString());
                onWeatherInfoRecieved.onRecieved(null);

            }
        });
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(8000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private WeatherInfo parseResponseToWeatherInfo(JSONObject response){
        WeatherInfo weatherInfo= new WeatherInfo();
        try {
            JSONArray weatherJsonArray= response.getJSONArray("weather");

            JSONObject weatherJsonObject= weatherJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
            weatherInfo.setWeatherName(weatherJsonObject.getString("main"));
            weatherInfo.setWeatherName(weatherJsonObject.getString("description"));

            JSONObject mainJsonObject=response.getJSONObject("main");
            weatherInfo.setWeatherTemperature((float)mainJsonObject.getDouble("temp"));
            weatherInfo.setHumidity(mainJsonObject.getInt("humidity"));
            weatherInfo.setPressure(mainJsonObject.getInt("pressure"));
            weatherInfo.setMinTemperature((float)mainJsonObject.getDouble("temp_min"));
            weatherInfo.setMaxTemperature((float)mainJsonObject.getDouble("temp_max"));

            JSONObject windJsonObject=response.getJSONObject("wind");
            weatherInfo.setWindSpeed((float)windJsonObject.getDouble("speed"));
            weatherInfo.setWindDegree((float)windJsonObject.getDouble("deg"));

            return weatherInfo;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }


    }

    public interface OnWeatherInfoRecieved {
        void onRecieved(WeatherInfo weatherInfo);
    }
}
```

Edit:

My app has a button to request data from server. I want the user to type his city name in the EditText and the API address use that city name in it...

Someone told me I have to use the EditText value as QueryString and give it to the API.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving data from EditText in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498880/retrieving-data-from-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

To get value from EditText:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById("myEditText");
String city = edit.getText().toString();
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes but how to use that value in my code as the city name?

Answer (score 0):

To add city selection, you would have to call the remote openweathermap service and retrieve the cities.

For Openweathermap API, you can refer to [this tutorial](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/using-android-location-api-weather-app.html), which explains in detail how to add the city search option in your weather app. The final source code for it is on Github [here](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/WeatherLib). You can take a look in the [XML file](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/WeatherLib/blob/master/demo/src/main/res/layout/search_location_activity.xml) and the [Java Class](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/WeatherLib/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/survivingwithandroid/weatherapp/settings/SearchLocationActivity.java) specifically for the city selection in the sample application source code.